# How do I set the timezone in an iCal feed using DDay.iCal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, icalendar

I'm creating an iCal feed using [DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/). It works, but I can't figure out how to set the timezone for the feed. Here's the basic code:

```
iCalendar iCal = new iCalendar();

// <-- Set the Timezone HERE to PST (Pacific Daylight Time)

Event evt = iCal.Create<Event>();

evt.Start = new iCalDateTime(meeting.MeetDate);
evt.End = evt.Start.AddHours(4); // 4 hour event
evt.Description = "This meeting...";
evt.Summary = "Event Summary";
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

In the other answer, the author fails to mention the line above those three lines that's in example 6:

```
// First load a file containing time zone information for North & South America
IICalendar timeZones = iCalendar.LoadFromFile("America.ics")[0];
```

So that won't work. An option would be:

```
iCalendar iCal = new iCalendar();

System.TimeZoneInfo timezoneinfo = System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
iCalTimeZone timezone = iCalTimeZone.FromSystemTimeZone(timezoneinfo);
iCal.AddTimeZone(timezone);
```

Or simply add the local timezone:

```
iCalendar iCal = new iCalendar();
iCal.AddLocalTimeZone();
```

To find all registered timezones, use [this snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.id.aspx):

```
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> zones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
Console.WriteLine("The local system has the following {0} time zones", zones.Count);
foreach (TimeZoneInfo zone in zones.OrderBy(z => z.Id))
    Console.WriteLine(zone.Id);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

Example6 in the download is setting timezones and whatnot for events. Check that out.

Relevant lines:

```
IICalendar iCal = new iCalendar();
iCal.AddChild(timeZones.GetTimeZone("America/New_York"));
iCal.AddChild(timeZones.GetTimeZone("America/Denver"));            

// Set the event to start at 11:00 A.M. New York time on January 2, 2007.
evt.Start = new iCalDateTime(2007, 1, 2, 11, 0, 0, "America/New_York", iCal)
```