# How to set time zones with DDay.iCal

Tags: c#, timezone, icalendar, outlook-2013, dday

I am using [DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/) to send an event that should be received by Outlook 2013. This is the part of the code where I am setting the dates:

```
evt.Created = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now);
evt.LastModified = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now);
evt.UID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
evt.DTStamp = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now);
evt.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
evt.DTEnd = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(4));
```

When I receive the corresponding meeting request in Outlook 2013, I am getting this:

> The organizer created this meeting in the following time zone: (UTC) Monrovia, Reykjavik

What time zones can I set? I have tried a few, such as:

```
evt.Created = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now, "GMT");
evt.LastModified = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now, "GMT");
evt.UID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
evt.DTStamp = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now, "GMT");
evt.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
evt.DTEnd = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(4), "GMT");
```

...and...

```
evt.Created = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now, "Eastern Standard Time");
evt.LastModified = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now, "Eastern Standard Time");
evt.UID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
evt.DTStamp = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now, "Eastern Standard Time");
evt.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
evt.DTEnd = new iCalDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(4), "Eastern Standard Time");
```

When I do this, instead of a meeting request, in Outlook 2013 I get an email with an attachment called `not supported calendar message.ics`.

How can I set the time zone correctly (or at least some default setting, so that Outlook won't show the message mentioned earlier)?

**Edit**: below is the content of the .ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20140602T094431
DESCRIPTION:Test test
DTEND:20140602T134431
DTSTAMP:20140602T074431Z
DTSTART:20140602T094431
LAST-MODIFIED:20140602T094431
ORGANIZER:mailto:johnny@example.com
PRIORITY:3
SEQUENCE:1
SUMMARY:Test 2
UID:df6b9f7c-2986-49f1-8b46-78d50193904c
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:Display
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
DURATION:PT15M
TRIGGER:PT15M
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Please post the contents of one of the generated .ics files? i.e. Open the file in a text editor and post the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9178327/983064) solved the problem for me. The solution was to use:

```
iCal.AddLocalTimeZone();
```

It is also possible to set arbitrary time zones based on system timezones... see that answer for details.